# Custom Registration with Select and Upload function

Tags: user-registration, post-meta

I have a custom Registration form in my functions.php

```
    // Registration

    add_action('register_form','register_extra_fields');
    function register_extra_fields(){
    ?>

    <div class="register-wrapper step-1 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">

    <?php if( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

        <h4 class="subtitle register-headline"><span>Your account</span></h4>

        <div class="form-wrapper col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">

        <form action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post">

        <label><?php _e('First Name') ?></label>
        <input id="user_fname"  type="text" size="25" value="<?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>" name="first_name"  class="text-input" tabindex="1"/>

        <label><?php _e('I’m interested in') ?></label><small>(Please select at least one option)</small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <input type="checkbox" id="chk-permanent" name="interested_in" value="Permanent" /><label for="chk-permanent"></label><span class="chk-label">Permanent</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk-temporary" name="interested_in" value="Temporary" /><label for="chk-temporary"></label><span class="chk-label">Temporary</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk-interim" name="interested_in" value="Interim" /><label for="chk-interim"></label><span class="chk-label">Interim</span>

        <input id="uploadFile" name="upload_file" type="text" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-green">
            <span>Upload</span>
            <input id="upload_cv" type="file" class="upload" />
        </div>

        </form>

        </div>
```

Which gets updated as follows:-

```
add_action('user_register', 'register_post_fields');
function register_post_fields($user_id, $password='', $meta=array())  {
    $userdata = array();
    $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
    $userdata['first_name'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['first_name']);
    $userdata['interested_in'] = $_POST['interested_in'];
    $userdata['upload_file'] = $_POST['upload_file'];
    wp_update_user($userdata);
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name'] ); 
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'interested_in', $_POST['interested_in'] ); 
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'upload_file', $_POST['upload_file'] );  
}
```

The registration part is all working and I get get text fields to update. But items such as select options and upload files don't seem to be storing.

I am using ACF and I have added custom fields for the Users.

I can update any text fields that I have added for using ACF, but select and upload files I can't seem to store.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must use enctype="multipart/form-data" in the `<form>` tag for the file upload to work.